# How to make pagination of result in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP for my project in this here I get the result from the join query but by this I wanna make pagination on this result by using my way it's not possible.

**This is my code:**

```
$id= $this->Session->read('id');
$this->layout='ui_defualt';

$options['joins'] = array(array('table' => 'fj_bounty_watches','conditions' => array('fj_bounty_watches.nBountyID = FjBounty.id')));

$options['conditions'] = array('fj_bounty_watches.nHeadHunterID' =>$id);

$watchedbounty = $this->FjBounty->find('all', $options);
```

Using this, I get the result as an array. It does not perform pagination on it.

How can I get pagination on this result?

Answer (score 0):

You should get paginated results if you use the correct setup:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup

Answer (score 0):

you can set the pagination parameters just like with the `find` method:

**YourModel Controller:**

```
$this->paginate['YourModel'] = array(   'recursive' => -1,
                                        'fields'    => array('YourModel.*','OtherModel.*'),
                                        'joins'     => $joins, // an array of joins
                                        'order'     => array('YourModel.creation'),
                                        'conditions'=> $conditions, 
                                        'limit'     => 10
                                );
$this->set('myPaginatedList', $this->paginate('YourModel'));
```

and also, i see that your join array is not quite respecting the naming convention, it should be something like:

```
array(  'table' => 'fj_bounty_watches',
        'alias' => 'FjBountyWatches',
        'type' => 'INNER', // or left, or right
        'conditions' => array('FjBountyWatches.nBountyID = FjBounty.id'))
```

Good Luck